# Trigonometry puzzling problem

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]

Contructed the figure here reported and known that $AB=2r$, $AC=r\sqrt{2}$ and fixed $x:=P\hat{A}C$, it is asked to find 
$$ y = CK + PH \sqrt{2} + PK $$

as a function of $x$.

I started with

$$PH = AP\sin x$$

but I can't see how to see the other lengths missing.

Can anyone give me some suggestions? I don't know how to go on....

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, $AC=\sqrt2 r$ entails $\angle CAB=45°$, and consequently $\angle AOP=90°-2x$ and $\angle COP=2x$, where $O$ is the center of the circle (midpoint of $AB$). That is enough to compute $y$.

Comment: thanks to everybody.... I'll put together everything!

Comment: Be warned that $KC$ is not, in general, tangent to the circle.

Comment: Now I see that $C\hat{A}B=45°$. It's also ok that $A\hat{O}P+C\hat{O}P=90°$, but could you explain why the consequence of $C\hat{A}B=45°$ is that $A\hat{O}P=90°-2x$? I just have $O\hat{A}P=45°+x$ but not $A\hat{P}O$....

Comment: Triangle $AOP$ is isosceles, with base angle $\angle PAO=45°+x$ and vertex angle $\angle AOP=180°-2\angle PAO$.

Comment: so simple....thanks....

Answer (score 0):

The lines $PK$ and $KC$ both touch the circle. So if you fill the second half of the circle and add two more orthogonal lines, the circle will be boxed in a square. The points $P$ and $C$ will be on the centres of the square's edges. So $PK = KC = r$.